# Uncaught ReferenceError in Chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

When I'm debugging my javascript I can't inspect my objects in the console.  They always throw the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: X is not defined(...)

You can see in the screenshot below that I've paused the debugger at activate()

The console.log() calls both properly display what's in the respective object but when I try to see the objects by typing them in the console I get the errors.

I'm using Chrome 45.0.2454.85 m

[image]

Comment: are you minifying the JS code and using a source map?

Comment: are you actually on the activate() line, or have you stepped into the activate function?

Comment: I'm minifying the JS code and using a source map.  Enable JavaScript source maps is checked in the settngs.

Comment: Minifiers usually changes variable & function names.

Comment: I have not stepped into the activate function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your code is minified, the variable and function names probably have changed.

If not:

`test` is only defined in the scope of userController, that's why you can not access it like this from the console.

`vm` is defined in the scope of userController aswell.

example:

```
var test = "1";
function foo(){
    var bar = "2";
    console.log(bar); #2
}

foo(); #will log "2"
console.log(test); #1
console.log(bar); #undefined
```

Comment: this is wrong, the console gives you the function stack as context

Comment: @sahbeewah only if you are using the debugger and are on the correct line.

Comment: Sorry but this answer doesn't make any sense... Maybe one of the upvoters might explain it in more detail, I don't understand how this is related at all.

Comment: @sotn if you're using some bundling software like webpack then your code is minified and source maps are generated. So what you see in the Sources tab in dev tools is code provided by source maps, but the actual names of variables may be different. For example, in my case, I was trying to access `hasOrgFeature` function but it's actual name was `_web_general_utils_organizationUtils__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__.hasFeature` and it should be accessed from console by that long name. That's why this answer was useful for me and I upvoted it.